# How to catch and modify a pdf, before browser gives it to download

Tags: javascript, add-on

I have the page. There is a button on that page, which has

> click.delegate="savePdf()"

As I am writing the add-on/"Chrome Extention" and I cant get inside this function and I cant get the data from elsewhere besides that PDF. I am wondering if there is a way to get that PDF before it will be given to download with that "savePdf" function, so I could modify it and put some data inside it? Maybe you have some other Ideas, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get inside this function for a very particular reason, security.

It is in no one's best interest for you to inject whatever data you see fit into a downloaded PDF like this. What is the context for this scenario?

Do you host the PDF? If so, add the data on the serving process before it hits the browser/client.

Do you not own the PDF? If so, it is quite unethical for you to inject data into someones else content before it arrives at the user.

Comment: Yes we are the owners of that PDF. Can you please show an example how to "add the data on the serving process"?

Comment: You have not provided enough information for me to answer that. If you wish to add info to a PDF programmatically you will need to post an entirely new question with more relevant technical detail. Or, perhaps update this question with some relevant code snippets and information. 

Also, did you downvote my answer? If so I believe you should accept it as I have handled this question as best as possible with the given information.

Comment: Thanks. I havent downvoted it, but I  upwoted it now..

Comment: Did you create another question relevant to whatever process serves the PDF? With some more details, I can provide more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

you can't modify pdf with browser Javascript, but you can modify/intercept function

```js
function savePdf() {
  console.log('downloading pdf')
}

var oldSavePdf = savePdf;

savePdf = function() {
  console.log('downloading from other location')
  //oldSavePdf();
}

savePdf();
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I cant get that old function(it is hidden). Then there is no way to do that?